# Show Filtered Lookup in CRM2011 from Silverlight Grid

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I recently show up all products on a "Lookup" Field on a Inline Silverlight App on the CRM2011 Quote form.

I do this with directly calling the link of the Lookup:

```
    var uri = (ScriptObject)crmUri.Invoke("create", string.Format("/_controls/lookup/lookupinfo.aspx?LookupStyle=single&objecttypes={0}", objectType));

    var dArgs = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("Object");
    dArgs.SetProperty("items", new string[] { "" });

    dynamic dlgResult = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("showModalDialog", uri, dArgs, "dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:700px");
```

Our Customer wants to filter the lookup view on a value of a specific field on the product form.

This field is a optionset and can be 1 or 2.

I tried to add `"&$filter=" + "producttypecode/Value" + " eq 1"` or `"&$filter=" + "producttypecode" + " eq 1"`   in the link, but this always Returns a error message.

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid request that I just tested.

```
ProductSet?$filter=ProductTypeCode/Value eq 1
```

If that doesn't work I'd recommend the following troubleshooting steps.

1. Test your full URL in a browser first.
2. If it works in a browser then fire up fiddler and see what the difference is between the silverlight request and your manual request using a browser.
3. If you are having difficulty determining the correct full url I'd recommend downloading and becoming familiar with the CRM OData Query Designer.  It will allow you to use a GUI to generate your request strings, and test them out.  It can be found here.

http://crm2011odatatool.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by adding a new System View and call it from its URL.